# How can I manage how many live subscribers for a topic in Appsync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I am using AWS Appsync for graphql subscription. It works fine and i can see Appsync manages all the hard stuff. But what is not clear to me is that how I can see how many subscribers are subscribing `Appsync`? 
Is there an API I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are asking for is commonly referred as "presence" detection. It is a popular ask and AppSync doesn't support it out of the box. 
However you can implement it yourself using a atomic counter in a DynamoDB table to keep track of your connected clients. [Detect Presence in AWS AppSync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59761224/detect-presence-in-aws-appsync)

You can also create an issue and +1 it on the https://github.com/aws/aws-appsync-community/issues repository, it helps us prioritizing features.